# Cannot add pagination info to response in the generated swagger

Tags: .net-core, pagination, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have a web application based on .Net 2.2 and I'm generating it's Swagger.json using Swashbuckle that I set up using [it's github page](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore).
My problem is that the pagination information does not show in the '200' response type. There should be a list of paginated results but instead, it shows only the result object, without pagination.

I've tryed different configurations based on Swashbuckle's github page and also tryed to annotate PaginatedList Class' attributes with [required] annotation. Couldn't move forward.

In the Startup.cs I'm using Mvc and set the Compatibility version to 2.2:

```
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
```

and I have the following Swagger configuration:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(swaggerSetup =>
        {
            swaggerSetup.CustomSchemaIds(type => type.ToString());


            swaggerSetup.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo()
            {
                Title = "Web App",
                Version = "v1",
                Description = "**descript**",


            });


            swaggerSetup.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                ...
            });




            var xmlFile = $"...";
            var xmlPath = Path.Combine(BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
            swaggerSetup.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);


            swaggerSetup.AddFluentValidationRules();


            swaggerSetup.DocumentFilter<UserIdFilter>();
            swaggerSetup.OperationFilter<JWTAuthOperationAttribute>();
        });
```

My controller:

```
    [HttpGet("findAllItemsByStatus/{status}")]
    [Authorize]
    [Consumes("application/json")]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(GetListItemsResult), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Errors), StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> getList([FromQuery] GetListItems request, string status)
    {
        request.UserId = _securityTokenProvider.GetAuthenticatedUserID(HttpContext);
        request.ItemType = status;


        return Ok(await _mediator.Send(request));
    }
```

GetListItems class definition:

```
public class GetListItems : IRequest<PaginatedList<ItemDTO, GetListItemsResult>>
    {
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public string ItemType { get; set; } = "active";
        public int Page { get; set; } = 1;
        public int PerPage { get; set; } = 10;
    }
```

Handler class definition:

```
public class GetListItemsHandler : UserAuthBasedQuery<GetListItems, PaginatedList<ItemDTO, GetListItemsResult>>
```

and it's handle method has the following signature:

```
public override async Task<PaginatedList<ItemDTO, GetListItemsResult>> Handle(GetListItems request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

PaginatedList Class:

```
public class PaginatedList<T, TOut> where T : class
{
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int PerPage { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TOut> Data { get; set; }


    public static async Task<PaginatedList<T, TOut>> FromIQueryableAsync(IQueryable<T> query, int page, int perPage, Func<T, TOut> formatterCallback) {
        var thisPage = await query
            .Skip((page - 1) * perPage)
            .Take(perPage)
            .ToListAsync();
        
        var total = await query.CountAsync();


        return new PaginatedList<T, TOut>{
            Page = page,
            PerPage = perPage,
            Total = total,
            Data = thisPage.Select(i => formatterCallback(i))
        };
    }        
}
```

The generated Swagger, where the response for status code 200 is not a paginated list but the result object itself:

```
'/api/v1/Item/findAllItemsByStatus/{status}':
    get:
      tags:
        - Item
      summary: Lists all Items by status
      description:
        The status can be:
        active
        inactive
        expired 
      operationId: Item_getList
      parameters:
        - name: userId
          in: query
          schema:
            type: string
            format: guid
          nullable: false
        - name: ItemType
          in: query
          schema:
            type: string
          nullable: false
        - name: page
          in: query
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int32
          nullable: false
        - name: perPage
          in: query
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int32
          nullable: false
        - name: status
          in: path
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
          x-position: 1
      responses:
        '200':
          description: ''
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/GetListItemsResult'
        '403':
          description: ''
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Errors'
```

Comment: I'm not sure I got your point... You wrote `[ProducesResponseType(typeof(GetListItemsResult), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]` so its displays `GetListItemsResult` as model. Why don't you write `[ProducesResponseType(typeof(GetListItems), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]` instead?

Comment: @BrunoMartins I'm storing results in GetListItemsResult object. But the question still remains: Why does not show it's pagination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've found the solution:

```
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(PaginatedList<ItemDTO, GetListItemsResult>), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
PaginatedList<AuctionDTO, GetListAuctionsResult>
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Errors), StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> getList([FromQuery] GetListItems request, string status)
    {
...
}
```

I have to use the type "**PaginatedList<ItemDTO, GetListItemsResult>**" in the response type. I was thinking that the Swashbuckle will pick up inner types *(the return type of the handler)* correctly but I was wrong, I have to specify the exact type (the paginated list in my case) in the controller's annotation.